# PHP Mysql special character issue. Record did not insert in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

My website http://www.locuciones-baratas.com/
There are many textarea where user can input text. But when user input text with special character like

1.000 millones de pesetas"
|#~@¬#~€¬€~¬'''¡¡!"!!
"Yo he ahorrado al PP más de 1.000 millones de pesetas", ha asegurado Correa, explicando que esa cifra se corresponde con el

then record won't  insert into mysql database

I tried
ut8 general ci as character set.

Set meta utf8 in html

```
$textarea = mb_convert_encoding($_POST['textarea'], 'ISO-8859-1','utf-8');
$insert_array = array('textarea'=>$textarea);
$sql = build_sql_insert('order',$insert_array); 
mysqli_query($conn,$sql) ;

function build_sql_insert($table, $data) {

$key = array_keys($data);
$val = array_values($data);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (" . implode(', ', $key) . ") " . "VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $val) . "')";
return($sql); 
    }
```

I think problem may be php dont allow special character to further proceed, data may be don't reach to mysql.

Please advice how to insert record with such text

Comment: Probably you do not bind your variable into query. But without code I can only have a guess

Comment: Have you changed the field's collation to `utf8`?

Comment: We cannot give a clear answer since you chose not to include the relevant parts of your code into the question which is clearly required. Most likely you did not take care to treat characters you receive from the client side the way they have to be treated, but simply accept them in good trust. That may not only fail, it often is a huge security issue. You need to escape those characters, best by using the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" in your database abstraction layer.

Comment: @KinshukLahiri, yes I have changed to utf8

Comment: @J.Rob Please provide the insertion code.

Comment: @arkascha requirement is to insert record with such special character

Comment: @J.Rob There is no such thing as a "special character". What should be special about them? There are only characters, lot's of em buggers.

Comment: @J.Rob The issue described is that nothing get's inserted into the database, not something wrong. That implies that the insert statement does not work, crashes. This is not because of some wrong encoding.

Comment: @arkascha added more to clear

Comment: @KinshukLahiri provided the insertion code.

Comment: The issue is _not_ that "php dont allow special character"! The issue is exactly what I wrote in that bigger comment above: you do not escape the characters you receive when using them inside your sql query. That leads to invalid query syntax if you are lucky, if not your system can get compromised by that (sql injection attacks). Please read about the topics I mentioned, you will find endless examples about how to do that. There is no way around doing that. Your current code is a security gap.

Comment: Apply mysqli_real_escape_string() on each inserting values.

Answer (score 1):

After the connection creation ($conn = .....) try to add this line:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to escape strings.

Try adding mysqli_real_escape_string.

```
function build_sql_insert($table, $data, $conn) {

    $key = array_keys($data);
    $val = array_values($data);

    //Mysql real escape string use a string value. this hack will work only 
    //for a single value passed. please read the comment below.
    $val[0] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $val[0]);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (" . implode(', ', $key) . ") " . "VALUES ('" .     implode("', '", $val) . "')";
    return($sql); 
}
```

More information in php manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: I need to preserver those character. don't want to remove it.

Comment: Definitively escaping the string is the solution.

I have tested your function, mysqli_real_escape_string don't remove characters. 

The code I pasted don't work correctly, sorry: leaved $city variable instead of $val[0].This is because $val is an array and not a single string.
You should use $val[0] in the mysqli_real_escape_string line:

$val[0] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $val[0]);

This is a single case use solution to made something that work you should made a loop to iterates trough each $val position and escape each value.